# NameError: name 'boto3' is not defined

Tags: python, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, boto3

I am working with jupyter and python, and am getting the error 'NameError: name 'boto3' is not defined', even though I have it installed and upgraded. I have attached some code. Thank you!

```
pip install boto3 --user
pip install boto3 --upgrade
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

Comment: Just do `import boto3` before `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`

Comment: @jellycsc Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import the boto3 library before using it in Python ◡̈

```python
import boto3
```